# Applying for Facebook audience network is rejected

Tags: facebook

I apply for Facebook audience network a lots of times but I was rejected every time. Can anybody help me on this developer audience network? What are the requirements. Is there any reason my application got rejected?.

Comment: What is the response you get?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, but it about Facebook's ad network policies

Comment: @lgy you know what this helped me way more than programming questions. I do not agree with your "voting".

Answer (score 2):

This is a story why I cannot recommend to waste your time with Audience Network.
As an indie developer I've decided to try Facebook Audience Network to show ads in my mobile application. After I spent hours to make all the integration stuff and filled out all required registration info my application was successfully approved to the network.

But it was still blocked from showing ads because of the bug - I was not able to add bank info to the Payouts in Monetization Manager because it is treated my SWIFT number as invalid one. So I've made a support ticket and attached screenshot with error. In response I got following answer:

> Thank you for applying for Audience Network. At this time we are
> unable to accept your application. We thank you for your patience
> while we determine the ideal process for bringing new publishers on to
> the network.

I was shocked about such response as my application was still approved, so reply was totally irrelevant to the problem. There was no explanations on the topic and ticket was closed without a chance to appeal. so I created a new ticket where I asked about reasoning for such response. To my surprise I received exactly same answer as previous one.
After sending few additional emails to support I received an update which does not give any additional information and only confirms Facebook ignorance to developers:

> Thank you for reaching back to us. We currently do not have any
> further information to offer. We seek your kind understanding on this
> matter.

I’ve spent more time trying to get an answer and after a week of waiting I've got another useless answer:

> I would like to let you know that your case has been reviewed by our
> Internal team in detail earlier and under these circumstances, the
> team has decided to maintain the original decision. The application
> has been disapproved and unfortunately we cannot provide any further
> insight on this issue.

I never break any rules and even spent money to promote my app with Facebook ads previously, but Facebook showed that they don’t care about your problems and don’t respect developers or their time.

As a conclusion I suggest for everyone to avoid my mistake and do not spend your time to just get such a crap from Facebook.

UPDATE:
After half a year they did some updates in Audience Network and now it displays a message that they do not work with my country yet (Ukraine). It is still ridicuolus that support was not able to provide this information after numerous requests.

Comment: Faced the very same issue. Any communication with Facebook team feel like you talking to a robots.